# How to make multiple rows from a single row in R?

Tags: r, web-scraping

I currently have a data set that has all information within one single row (or column if I transpose). The very first items in the data are actually column names:

| Country | Population | O+ | A+ | B+ | AB+ | O- | A- | B- | AB- |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Albania | 3,074,579 | 32.1% | 31.2% | 14.5% | 5.2% | 6.0% | 5.5% | 2.6% | 0.9% |
| Algeria | 43,576,691 | 5019 | 40.0% | 30.0% | 15.0% | 4.25% | 6.6% | 2.3% | 1.1% |
| Argentina | 45,479,118 | 8017 | 48.9% | 2.45% | 4.9% | 3.16% | 0.8% | 0.25% | ... |
| Armenia | 3,021,324 | 8870 | 29.0% | 46.3% | 12.0% | 5.6% | 2.0% | ... | ... |

The problem is that right now, my table has all these values within ONE single column (or row if I transpose).

How can I make sure to have a new row at each country?

I'm truly just trying to web scrape the blood type distribution by country table found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_type_distribution_by_country) but after attempting to do so, I have encountered this problem. Help on either would be appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: If it really is one column, `BloodType <- matrix(OneCol, nrows, ncols)` might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

baseurl=("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_type_distribution_by_country")
fullurl=URLencode(baseurl)
tables = read_html(fullurl) %>% 
  html_table(fill = TRUE)

df = tables[[2]]
```